# Careers page truncating the University Name

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

On my CV [Steven Hicks](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/stevenhicks), the University name is being truncated. I've selected my University from the drop down but when saving it saves the value as "University Of Nort Carol" rather than the full name (Carolina at Charlotte).

Comment: It also doesn't take my University: University of)'; drop table users; --

:)

Comment: Shame... I did my best work at that univers.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on some client-side javascript issues with the autocomplete -- don't autocomplete if you're running into this, hit ESC and enter it manually.

However, we also have a fix in place so when you click [Save], it should correct this!

Comment: I did click save after using autocomplete.

Comment: I believe the fix was deployed around 8 am PST -- try again and see.

Comment: Ah yes - I remember now. I eventually "fixed" my problem by typing it in full and not using the auto-complete.

Answer (score 0):

I had this with my university, but editing it again sorted the problem out. It now displays in full.

Comment: I've tried editing several times, but it keeps doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing - my first school, "Hudson Valley Community College", renders properly.

I wonder if it has to do with non-capitalized words in the name?

(pure speculation)